# Problem getting the decimal separator setting in Windows

Tags: c++builder, vcl, regional-settings

I hope you can help me to solve this.
I am building a Windows VCL application with C++ Builder. I have a Tedit object in which the user should type a temperature value, 25.35 for example. Before processing it, I need to check if the number is written correctly and, in particular, I need to check if the decimal separator is correct comparing it to the Windows 10 settings. In case the separator is wrong, it should be automatically set correctly and re-write the Text of the Tedit object.

I wrote this code:

```
char separator = std::use_facet< std::numpunct<char> >(std::cout.getloc()).decimal_point();
AnsiString str = refTemperature->Text;

if (separator == ',') {
    str = StringReplace( str, ".", separator, TReplaceFlags() <<rfReplaceAll );
}
else
    str = StringReplace( str, ",", separator, TReplaceFlags() <<rfReplaceAll );

refTemperature->Text = str;
```

Here, separator is always ".", even when my Windows Control Panel settings are Decimal symbol = ',' and Digit grouping symbol = '.'. So, in this case, the code does not work. Have got a solution? Thank you.

Comment: The RTL aleady gets that for you, in  SysUtils TFormatSettings->DecimalSeparator. See [the documentation here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings)

Comment: Why do you even need this? When the time comes to actually parse `refTemperature->Text` for processing, you could just normalize it at that time to whatever decimal separator you want, eg: `String str = StringReplace(refTemperature->Text, _D(","), _D("."), TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll); TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create(); fmt.DecimaSeparator = _D('.'); double dblTemp = StrToFloat(str, fmt); // use dblTemp as needed ...`

Comment: Thank you very much @Ken White for your suggestion

Comment: Thank so much @Remy Lebeau for providing the real code. Please, write it as answer so I can mark it. (There is only a very small typo in fmt.DecimalSeparator = _D('.');)